# Dynamically added link causes doubletap issue in Chrome on iOS - looking for fix / workaround

Tags: javascript, html, chrome-ios

**Issue:**
User has to tap link twice to open it.

**Expected behaviour:**
After replacing the content, first tap on any link should open a page on new tab.

**Current behaviour:**
After replacing the content, first tap doesn't open the link. Second tap is required.

**Minimal code example:**
Insert into any HTML page (5s timeout added for convenience):

```
<div id="dynamic-content">Content before change</div>
<script>
    function timedPassback() {
        let content = "<div style='width: 300px; height: 300px; background: olive; color: white; text-align: center; font-size: 2rem'><a href='//stackoverflow.com/'>Content after change</a></div>"
        let element = document.getElementById("dynamic-content");
        element.innerHTML = content;
    }
    setTimeout(timedPassback, 5000);
</script>
```

**Example page**
https://putzj.github.io/ioschromebug/

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open the page containing script in Chrome on iOS
2. Make a scrolling gesture (the page doesn't have to scroll)
3. Wait for the content to be replaced with olive square
4. Click any link on the page

**Environment:**
iPhone 8
Chrome 107.0.5304.101
iOS 15.2

**Debug info:**
Can't debug Chrome on iOS. There is no tool that works and allows any remote debugging of this issue (tried it on MacOs, Windows and Ubuntu).

**Additional info**
I doubt it's a feature of Chrome.
I already reported it as a bug.
I searched the web, didn't find any clues on how to fix it or any workarounds.
The issue can be reproduced on 4 different iPhones I have access to.

Comment: In unlikely case this question will be reopened, I managed to find a workaround myself by accident. Adding this code to the bottom of the page removes the issue, but there may be better approach.


```
(function () {
  if (navigator.userAgent.match('CriOS')) {
    let bumper = document.createElement("div");
    bumper.style.cssText = "position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%";
    document.body.append(bumper);
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", function () {
      bumper.remove();
    });
  }
})();
```

Comment: This just helped me get around the same bug. Doing a very similar thing with links on the homepage of my site and it was having this exact behavior on Chrome iOS only. Thank you so much friend.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the solution which i picked it from comments to show explicility to everyone. I had a problem same issue and fixed it.

```
(function () { if (navigator.userAgent.match('CriOS')) { let bumper = document.createElement("div"); bumper.style.cssText = "position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%"; document.body.append(bumper); document.addEventListener("touchstart", function () { bumper.remove(); }); } })();
```